# Can I send trought FTP a recorded audio file with a sim800 gsm module

Tags: ftp, gsm, sim800

hello I would like to know if someone succeed in sending a recorded audio file trough ftp with a sim800 gsm module.
Here what I'm able to do :

I'm connected into the net(AT+CIFSR:10.169.xxx.xxx)
I can record an audio amr file during a call (AT+CREC=1,2,0 to record(1) audio to id 2, and AT+CREC=2 to stop the record), check recorded file (at+CREC=7 +CREC: 7,1,6118,0 and +CREC: 7,2,6118,0 )

My ftp param are in, I can check with AT+FTPSCONT?                                                                                          +FTPSCONT: 0                                                                                          +FTPSERV: "ftpperso.free.fr"                                                                                          +FTPPORT: 21                                                                                          +FTPUN: "james"                                                                                            +FTPPW: "dean"                                                                                            +FTPCID: 1                                                                                            +FTPMODE: 1
+FTPTYPE: "I"                                                                                         +FTPPUTOPT: "STOR"                                                                                    +FTPREST: 0                                                                                           +FTPGETNAME: ""                                                                                       +FTPGETPATH: ""                                                                                       +FTPPUTNAME: ""                                                                                       +FTPPUTPATH: ""                                                                                       +FTPTIMEOUT: 0
I don't have a sd card connector,

my question is : how can I send file id 2 or 1 into the ftp. I can't figure it. need your help

I tried to find where file id 2 is stored to send it troughht ftp with right instructions